# Unsure how to send error code if command within a shell script fails

Tags: shell, exit-code

I recently learned about an if statement that looks at previous command and if failed will send exit code 1 with a message. I can't remember the entire statement but it starts with the below:

```
if [ $? != "0" ]
```

How does this statement end? Does it follow every command within a script?

Comment: You need to quote the variable, not the explicit value.  Your example would be better written `if [ "$?" != 0 ]`.  Although neither set of quotes is really necessary in this case. And you ought to be using `-ne` to compare integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that.  Explicitly referencing `$?` is almost never necessary.  If you want to exit with status 1 when a command fails, you can simply do:

```
cmd || exit 1
```

If you want to exit with the same non-zero value returned by the command, you can simply do:

```
cmd || exit
```

There are a lot of examples of bad code out there that instead do things like:

```
cmd
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then echo cmd failed >&2; exit 1; fi
```

and this is bad practice for many reasons.  There's no point in having the shell print a generic message about failure; the command itself ought to have written a detailed error message already, and the vague "cmd failed" is just line noise.  Also, you will often see `set -e`, which basically slaps a `|| exit` on the end of every simple command but has a lot of unintended side effects and edge cases, and its implementation has changed throughout history and different versions of the same shell will handle the edge cases differently so it's really not a good idea to use it.

As to the question "how does this statement end?"; it ends with `fi`.  The general form of `if` is `if CMD; then ...; else ...; fi` where CMD is some set of pipelines (eg, you can do `if echo foo | grep bar; cmd2 | foo; then ....`).  If the CMD returns a 0 status the first set of commands (between "then" and "else") is executed.  If CMD returns non-zero, the commands between "else" and "fi" are executed.  The "else" clause is optional.  Don't be fooled by `[`; it is simply a command.  In my opinion, it would be clearer if you used its alternate spelling `test`, which does not require a final argument of `]`.  IOW, you could write `if test "$?" -ne 0; then ...; fi`.

Comment: What do you mean?  If you already have `cmd` in the script, just append `|| exit` to the end of it.

Comment: if [ -f "/usr/tmp/testfile" ];
 then
  echo "The File Exists";
fi || exit

Comment: The entire `if` statement will always succeed, so the RHS (the exit) will never execute.  It looks like you just want `if [ -f /usr/tmp/testfile ]; then echo /usr/tmp/testfile exists >&2; exit 1; fi` . Don't forget to write error messages to stderr.

Comment: OOOOooooo gotcha, thanks! I'll dig more into the rest of your answer too, just wanted to fully grasp where the exit goes.